# Spring Boot: Best approach for aggregating DTOs over multiple services

Tags: mvc, spring-boot

I have the following situation in my spring boot application:

I use unidirectional relationship modelling for my database entities, in order to prevent difficulties with a bidirectional approach. (Cascading, Updating both sides etc.) Of course I don't want to expose this structure to the presentation layer, thus my DTOs are compositions over multiple tables. Now I have the following question:
How do I properly aggregate this DTOs?

At the moment I have a datacomposition service, which calls the relevant services and builds the DTOs. This service is transactional, because otherwise I could create something in one service, but won't be able to roll it back if something goes wrong in antother one. This is cleanest approach I came up with. Before my controller did this work, but this was a bad idea because of the transaction handling.
My Problem with this approach is that this datacomposition service returns DTOs, which I don't like since I belong to the group saying, that the service layer only deals with domain objects. Is this acceptable?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `the service layer only deals with domain objects.`  Why?

Comment: @Laiv: This is due to the definition of what a service is. If you look at at from a DDD or Martin Fowler point of view, a service only deals with domain objects

Comment: @msts1906 Neither DDD nor Martin Fowler are authoritative sources for a definition of the term "service".

Comment: It's true that `DDD` has an element named service with a particular scope and goal, but this is not incompatible with having more services, at different layers (app layer for example) doing the mapping you need. **There's no such a thing as a unique service layer**. That's something springbooters developers fail to understand.